# Нет выбора шаблона страницы в свойствах страницы Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

В админке сайта на `Wordpress` не могу выбрать шаблон страницы. Создал разные шаблоны, но в админке в свойствах страницы даже нет выпадающего списка.

Сделал все из [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987773/template-dropdown-not-showing-up-within-wordpress-administrator-page)  и не помогло.

Вот [тема](https://github.com/SimonPadbury/b4st). Кто-то сталкивался?

Comment: проверьте на наличие файл style.css в главной директории темы .

Comment: да, все присутствует, вроде и прописано верно...

Comment: может скрыт блок самой темой что то типа https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145496/how-to-hide-and-not-to-remove-the-attributes-metabox

Comment: все решил. Там автор темы лишний коммент написал в style.css. Все отобразилось